# Show that the $\ell_p$ norm of $x$ as $p \to 0$ is the support of $x$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, reference-request, normed-spaces, sparsity

I have seen in many compressed sensing books which say that

$$\lim_{p\to 0} \|x\|_p = \lim_{p\rightarrow 0}\left(\sum^n_{i=1}|x_i|^p\right)^{1/p} = \mbox{supp}\left(x\right)=\text{#} \{x_k:x_k \neq 0\} = \texttt{no. of non-zero elements of x}$$

where $\mbox{supp}\left(x\right)$, or support of $x$, is the number of non-zero elements of $x$.

I have no idea how to prove it. I have seen various other questions and their corresponding answers but none clearly states a process to obtain the proof. Is there any book where a proof is given? How should one start this proof?

Comment: Has this question been badly misunderstood? This book is actually pretty mathematical, and the question is relevant. Personally, it *could* be a duplicate, and I'll search for one, but if it's not then I'm voting to reopen. This [generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406992/let-f-omega-to0-infty-and-lnx-be-mu-integrable?noredirect=1) is the closest I could get (in proof technique), so I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: @user1046533 Please do not edit a question to introduce context or sources which were not originally given by the original asker.  It would be reasonable to leave a comment to *suggest* a citation, but the content of the question needs to come from the original asker.

Comment: It is the job of the *asker* to make those kinds of edits.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Is it you who deleted OP's comment regarding the book?

Comment: The statement doesn't even seem to be true. Take $x = (1,1)$; then $||x||_p = 2^{1/p}$, which goes to infinity as $p$ goes to $0$. Perhaps the intended statement is $\lim_{p\to 0^+} \|x\|_p^p = |\mathrm{supp}(x)|$?

Comment: whatever the reason for the missing book, it [seems](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34447/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2022-today#comment164839_35063) to be the book linked in this comment

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in a comment, the correct statement is that:
$$
\lim_{p \rightarrow 0^+} \|x\|_p^p = |\text{supp}(x)|
$$
Which you can derive from the simple observation:
$$
\lim_{p \rightarrow 0^+} |x_k|^p = \begin{cases}0 & x_k = 0 \\ 1 & x_k \ne 0\end{cases}
$$

I think you may have heard people say things like "minimizing the support of $x$ is like minimizing $\|x\|_p$ for small $p$". But keep in mind that if $f$ is a nonnegative function and $p$ is a positive number, then minimizing $f$ is equivalent to minimizing $f^p$, so the two notions are sometimes conflated.

Comment: Interesting : even the textbook got this wrong (it wrote $\|x\|_p \to |supp(x)|$ instead of $\|x\|_p^p \to |supp(x)|$).